# What is the intuition/connection between the tangent plane and differential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

True or False statement:

> If $f(x,y)$ is a linear function then $df$ is a linear function of
>   $dx$ and $dy$.

I said true for the following reasons:

True if we have a function $f(x,y) = ax + by + c$ where $a, b, c$ are any $\mathbb{R}$ then $df = adx + bdy$.

The book also got true but I don't get the intuition for the reason and I feel a bit like I'm just regurgitating a theorem without having any intuition why this is true.

The book doesn't really make any connections to these two ideas. They just give me the tools for calculating them. Is there a more intuitive way of connecting these two concepts?

I've tried solving for the differential equation here with respect to $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to gain more intuition. I obtained $y(x) = \frac{z(x)}{b} - \frac{ax}{b} + C$

[image]

[image]

I graphed the tangent plane and parameterized vector plot above, where I plugged in $a=2$, $b=3$, $c = 0$ and $C=0$. There is clearly a relationship between the two . Could someone help me gain more intuition why else the statement they made is true?

Comment: You mean $f(x,y) = a x + b y + c$.

Comment: Does it matter if it's c or d, it's just an arbitrary constant in \mathbb{R}?

Comment: It should not be $f(x,y) = a \, dx + b \, dy + c$.

Comment: I see thankyou @mvw

Answer (score 1):

For a function of two variables you have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
df 
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy
= \grad f \cdot du
$$
where $du = (dx, dy)^\top$.

$df$ is a linear function in $dx$ and $dy$ if the partial derivatives of $f$ are constant:
$$
\grad f = (f_x, f_y)^\top = \text{const}
$$
What can we say about $f$?

From integration, we have
$$
f(x,y) = f_x x + c_1(y) \\
f(x,y) = f_y y +  c_2(x)
$$
which combines into 
$$
f(x,y) = f_x x + f_y y + c
$$
which is a linear function.

[image]
[image]

(Large versions: [left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGdLx.png) and [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb70o.png))

We could also argue geometrically, that the gradient is orthogonal along lines of constant value of $f$ (isolines):
$$
\text{const} = f \Rightarrow \\
0 = df = \grad f \cdot du
$$
As the gradient was a constant vector, this means the isolines of $f$ are straight lines. This leaves $f$ a linear function.

The images above are for $f(x,y) = 2x + y - 2$ and $\grad f = (2,1)^\top$ and features isolines $f = c$ for $c \in \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5 \}$.

Comment: I've been thinking long and hard about what you said. I'm sorry if my example seems quite trivial. I'm just trying to understand what's going on here with the tangent plane approximation. Is it the case that the tangent plane linear approximation is the first few terms in a multivariable taylor series? I haven't been explicitly told this in my textbook but that seems to be what is going on?

Comment: It is also common in multi variable analysis to define the first derivative as the best approximating linear map, thus your tangent plane linear approximation. While the first order Taylor approximation is $\Delta f = \grad f \cdot \Delta u + O(h^2)$ and the total differential $df = \grad f \cdot du$. And your question was about $df$. E.g. if $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ you got $df = (2x, 2y) \cdot (dx, dy)$ so $df$ would not be a linear function of $dx$ and $dy$ IMHO.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GradientVectorTangentPlane.aspx